# change the name of the column when return a search using bookshelf with node/express?

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I have a table User with the column `id`, `email`, and `password`. But I want to return just the id and email and instead of showing the name of the column like this :

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "john@",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to show somethig like:

```
 {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "email_user": "john@",
            }
        ]
    }
```

This is how I make the call to search all the users:

```
User.fetchAll({columns:['id','email']}).then((resData) => {
        return res.json({users: resData.map(function(item) {
            return item.fields();
        })});
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer to the bookshelf document.

https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-hidden

To have alternate names for the columns with the same values. You can use bookshelf-virtuals-plugin to achieve that.

https://github.com/bookshelf/virtuals-plugin

**Example:**

```
bookshelf.plugin('bookshelf-virtuals-plugin');
const Users = bookshelf.model('Users', {
  tableName: 'users',
  hidden: ['password'],
  virtuals: {
    email: function () {
      return this.get("email_user");
    },
  },
})

User.fetchAll().then((resData) => {
    res.status(200).send(resData.toJSON({ virtuals: true }))
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Can we change the value of the result like mobile: '99999999999' => mobile:'XXXXXXXX9999'

Comment: @LaliteshUpadhyaya if you are looking to encrypt the phone number column in your database. you can use [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-encrypt-columns) **bookshelf-encrypt-columns**. Whereas you are asking to change the response of the phone number after getting it from database. You can write a simple logic to achieve that  let res = {
mobile: '9999999999'
}

res.mobile = res.mobile.replaceAll('9','X');

console.log(res).

Comment: Yes I got success with using events. Actually I want a generic solution for this instead of writing in each response.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your current code `item.fields()` returns the first of the two results. While you map, you should be able to create completely different objects, hence you can customize your results for your need:

```
User.fetchAll({columns:['id','email']}).then((resData) => {
    return res.json({users: resData.map(function(item) {
        const fields = item.fields();
        return { id: fields.id, email_user: fields.email };
    })});
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```